# Regex negate character without matching it

Tags: regex

Here's the data I need to fix:

```
{skin}\nstarts: head;\ndown to: trunk, extremities\n\nspares: palms, soles
```

I would like to put a `;` in front of the `\n` to turn it into the following:

```
{skin};\nstarts: head;\ndown to: trunk, extremities;\nspares: palms, soles
```

I came up with the following regex expression: `/[^;](\\n)+/`, but unfortunately it also matches the preceeding character (which is NOT what I want).

Any thoughts on how to proceed??

Comment: Match `(?<!;)(?:\\n)+` and replace with `;$0`

Comment: What should happen if input is `foo;\n\nbar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost agree with @anubhava: `(?<!;)(\\n)+`
I believe the OP wanted to exclude the `;` character from the match but not the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
;*(\\n)+
```

**Replace with**: `;$1`.

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/NNLi9K/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;*                       ';' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `\n\nspares:` should be turned into `;\nspares:`. It is fine as I use `;$1` as replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace any number of `\n` that *aren't* proceeded by a `;` or another `\n` with ';\n`:

```
Search: (?<!;)(?<!\\n)\\n+
Replace: ;\\n
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/vsEvGOCTpeUsuP).